# How can I make my JPanels/JFrames actually show up?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I have a widget designed to compile different pieces of information about each "plate", and each piece of information is stored in a JLabel. I've put all of the JLabels into a JPanel (one JPanel for each plate) and then put the JPanel into a JFrame, because that seemed to be the consensus on the internet for the best way to get the JPanel to actually show up. When I construct the widgets in another class, I create an array of widgets (one widget for each plate), so the goal is to have this array of widgets (which are really just a JFrame that holds a JPanel that holds several JLabels) appear. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, as I'm using setVisible() and I'm using the add(Component) method. Any input is very appreciated!!

```
public class BeltView extends JPanel implements BeltObserver {

    private Belt belt;
    private BeltViewWidget[] _widgets;

    public BeltView(Belt b) {
        this.belt = b;
        belt.registerBeltObserver(this);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(belt.getSize(), 1));
        _widgets = new BeltViewWidget[belt.getSize()];
        for (int i = 0; i < belt.getSize(); i++) {
            if (belt != null && belt.getPlateAtPosition(i) != null) {
                BeltViewWidget widget = new BeltViewWidget(belt, i);
                _widgets[i] = widget;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < _widgets.length; j++) {
            if (_widgets[j] != null) {
                add(_widgets[j]);
                _widgets[j].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Widget constructor (from widget class):

```
public BeltViewWidget(Belt belt, int position) {
    JPanel _widget_panel = new JPanel();
    JFrame _frame = new JFrame();
    _belt = belt;
    _position = position;
    Plate p = _belt.getPlateAtPosition(_position);
    _widget_panel.setVisible(true);
    _widget_panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    refresh();
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Consider instead displaying the widgets in a `JList` or `JTable` that is then put in the panel. It is usually a better approach for groups of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setTitle("My First Swing Application");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome");
frame.add(label);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

}

I dont think you are setting the _frame visible with true.

Comment: Thank you both! Will try that

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).